# Dart Aqueduct which version to use?

Tags: dart, aqueduct

Im having Dart SDK 2.10.4
Aqueduct in version 3.3.1

but for me it seems that those two don't work together well, e.g. do not connect to Postgres...

When i downgrade Dart to 2.7.2 the DB connection works fine, but im getting an error "Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version."

Can someone tell which versions they successfully use?

Comment: What error do you get when you try connect to Postgres? About `Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version` you properly need to call `pub get` again.

Comment: It is a bit tricky but with long searches on the internet i got it running with dart 2.10.4 and aqueduct 3.3.31 - the main problem with PostgreSQL was that i had to overwrite a dependency "postgres: 2.1.1"